# How to fix the net::err_aborted 415 with POST method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring

I'm trying to send a POST request to my Back-End but I get the "net::ERR_ABORTED 415" error.
I'm using Spring for the Back-End and React for the Front.
I have already disabled CORS because I had problems with it.
This is the React code:

```
const sendInfos = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch('http://localhost:9090/Register', {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: name,
            password: password,
            email: email
        })
    });
}
```

And this is the Java Spring code:

```
@RestController
public class RegistrationController {
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;

    @PostMapping(value = "/Register")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void PlayerRegistration(@RequestBody UserCredentials userDto) throws UserAlreadyRegisteredException{
        if(userDao.findByEmail(userDto.getEmail()) != null){
            throw new UserAlreadyRegisteredException("This email is already registered on the system.");
        }
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(userDto.getName());
        user.setPassword(encoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()));
        user.setEmail(userDto.getEmail());
        user.setElo(1200);
        userDao.save(user);
    }
}
```

I Already searched for an answer with my best friend "google", but all the answer I found don't work.
Does Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried `@postmapping(consumes = "application/json" )` or similar?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I resolved by simply adding an annotation on server side witch allow CORS.